# Static option menu android

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I want to create an static option menu in vertical.

[image]

What is the better option?

I see that action bar is not good for vertical options.

How can i create my own menu with vertical options?

Comment: What about navigation drawer?

Comment: yes. something like this. thanks. i will read it.

Comment: Read here >https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: if you want and example let us know :))

Comment: Thanks. I read it and it was very helpful for me.